# Downloading .ipa file in iphone 5s Os 8.3

Tags: ios, iphone

I test applications, so I get .ipa files to be downloaded on my iphone via dropbox in order to test them. I download them to my PC then via itunes to my iphone. I am unable to download ipa files,  when the installation reaches till the end, I always get the error message "Unable to download the file at this moment" I don't understand the reason. I have tried installing through itunes, through ifunbox, is there any solution to it?

Comment: Where do you download what? You said you download to test but then you said you can't download?!

Comment: Applications. They are .ipa files

Comment: I know. So where do you download what applicaitions?

Comment: I download the applications first on my Computer, then install it via itunes on my iphone

Comment: Not from the app store. i am provided by the company that wants me to test. Mostly via dropbox

Comment: So at what step do you experience the issue?

Comment: While downloading on my iphone, when the installation reaches till the end, it gives me "Unable to download" error.

Comment: 1. I get apps through drop box (These apps are for beta testing). 2. Download them on PC. 3. Transfer to itunes. 4. Install on Iphone. 5. Installation starts, when it reaches till end, it gives error "Unable to download the application"

Comment: Are these are Ad Hoc builds. If jailbreak since you mention ifunbox

Comment: I just tried ifunbox. no jailbreak

Comment: I don't know about this adhoc thing :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set proper **Provisioning Profile** with a valid *Developer Account* in [Apple Developer's Portal](http://developers.apple.com) 
before archiving or making an ipa file.

It might help you.

OR,

may be your DEVICE [UDID](http://whatsmyudid.com/) is not in the Provisioning Profile.

Comment: Developer would have to do this thing before providing it to me right?

Comment: YES, they have to make changes in Code Signing Section user Build Settings.